# En la página de 404, a la palabra "pagina" le falta una tilde

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones

[La página de 404 not found](https://es.stackoverflow.com/quiero-un-404) tiene el siguiente texto:

> ```
> Lo sentimos, no podemos encontrar la pagina que solicitaste.  
> --------------------------------------^ Falta tilde
> ```

Lo mismo pasa en [la página 404 de Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/quiero-un-404), busqué en [traducir.win](https://traducir.win/) pero sin éxito, lo mismo en el repositorio de las páginas de ayuda (se que ahí solo van los artículos de la sección de `/help`, pero quería averiguar antes de hacer el reporte en Meta). Y también busqué si ya existía el reporte en Meta, sin encontrar nada.

Dejo una captura de pantalla para la posteridad

> [image: Captura de pantalla de la página 404 mostrando que le falta una tilde a la palabra "pagina"]

Comment: Otra cosa de esa página que me chirría es esta coma: *Si crees que falta algo que debería estar aquí, comunícate con nosotros.*

Comment: @blonfu esa coma se puede sacar [en traducir.win](https://traducir.win/string/4168)

Comment: @g3rv4 como el OP ha dicho que no encontraba el texto pensé que no estaría ninguno de esa página. Luego lo busco

Comment: He enviado una sugerencia quitando la coma, creo que sobra pero quien lo revise que tome la decisión

Comment: aprobada, build hecho, y la coma ya no está en la página 404 \o/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listop! acento agregado :)

No es parte del código (sino que es un site setting), por lo que no es posible agregarlo a transifex.

Comment: En realidad, como dice el título, es tilde en vez de acento. Recuerdo haber aprendido esto en la secundaria. El acento se cambió de grave a esdrújula.